# Palette colors ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Can someone tell me how can I get this palette.
I'm using ggplot2 to plot the graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exact replica of the palette:

```r
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df$z <- factor(0:99 %% 13, levels = 12:0)


pal <- rev(c("#b86826", "#c9853a", "#e1a965", "#f5cd87", "#f4dea0", "#fef2be", 
"#ffffff", "#cfffcf", "#9cf2b1", "#4fc09c", "#70acc8", "#0272b3", 
"#053450"))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(21, "points"))
```

[image]